# Docusign: How does one send SMS and email signature requests for the same recipient?

Tags: docusignapi

How do I create a recipient with both email and SMS?

I've been unable to find example JSON that addresses this issue. The documentation on Docusign's website shows either email or SMS, not both together (that I can find, anyway). I found a note somewhere that suggested it's possible, but I can't find it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your account has SMS Delivery enabled, you can make an API Request in the following format to send an envelope with Email + SMS Delivery

```
{
"documents": [
    {
        "documentBase64": "Base 64 here",
        "documentId": 1,
        "fileExtension": "txt",
        "name": "Filename"
    }
],
"emailSubject": "Blurb",
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "Recipient Email Here",
            "name": "DocuSigner",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "10",
                        "yPosition": "10"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "additionalNotifications": [
                {
                    "secondaryDeliveryMethod": "SMS",
                    "phoneNumber": {
                        "countryCode": "Code",
                        "number": "Phone number"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"status": "sent"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use templateID, you can do the following:

```
{
  "templateId": "{template ID}",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateRoles": 
  [
    {
        "roleName": "{role}",
        "name": "{recipient name}",
        "phoneNumber": {
            "number": "{recipient  Phone number}",
            "countryCode": "{recipient  country code}"
        }
    },
    {
        "roleName": "{role}",
        "name": "{recipient  name}",
        "email": "{recipient  email}"
    }
 ]
}
```